# Debian Buster: Tesseract not supporting URL as argument

Tags: debian, tesseract

I'm trying to parse text from a hosted image, but it looks like I've miss-configured Tesseract. 
I'm using Debian Buster, `tesseract-ocr`, `libtesseract-dev` and a Ruby wrapper are installed.

```
#  $ tesseract -v
tesseract 4.0.0
 leptonica-1.76.0
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 6b (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.2) : libpng 1.6.36 : libtiff 4.1.0 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.0
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found SSE
```

Inside a terminal `tesseract <URL.png> output` returns `Error, cannot read input <URL.png>: No such file or directory`. The same error message is raised using the Ruby gem.

Did I miss something after installing the packages ?
The [doc](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki) talks about manually placing the traneddata directory on Ubuntu, should it also be done on Debian ?

> The traineddata is currently not shipped with the snap package and must be placed manually to ~/snap/tesseract/current.

I can get it working by using `curl` and local path as argument, but it should support URL as argument

Thanks

---

**EDIT**

I've tested both v4.1.1 and v5.0.0 by following [these](https://notesalexp.org/tesseract-ocr/) instructions and setting up tessdata directory. They both explicity returns that they don't support URLs:

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v5.0.0-alpha-647-g4a00 with Leptonica
Error, this tesseract has no URL support
Error during processing.
```

I'm obviously missing something because [release notes](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ReleaseNotes.html#tesseract-release-notes-dec-26-2019---v411) says it supports URL since 4.1.1

Comment: it looks like it's been added to 4.1.1. I'm about to test it and edit my question
https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ReleaseNotes.html

Comment: I have tesseract 4.1.1 installed via `apt`, and it still says "Error, this tesseract has no URL support".  Which is odd, as the error message suggests the program knows that some tesseracts do...